# How do I reshape the following array into the other one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I reshape the following numpy array with reshape:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

into this one:

```
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

Comment: Simply do `a.transpose()` or `a.T`!

Comment: `x=[[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]
y=np.transpose(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation that you are trying to achieve is a transpose.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
a.T # array([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Transpose it using - `x.T`

Output -

```
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```